# How to receive a decode_slice_header error as a return value from ffmpeg libav?

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, h.264, rtp, libav

I'm working on an MCU that decodes user h264 video stream using libav v5.1. I use WebRTC and RTP protocol to establish connection and transfer packets over the Internet. When network is congested I see some amount of packets being lost, which produce the following error on the libav side:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f8bd97f80c0] Frame num change from 77 to 7
[h264 @ 0x7f8bd97f80c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8bd97f80c0] Frame num change from 77 to 8
[h264 @ 0x7f8bd97f80c0] decode_slice_header error
and etc...
```

When network stabilise there's no packet loss but errors keep going and it seems like codec can't recover from previous packets being lost. It also results in a frozen video on the client. So I guess I need to send some Nacks or PLI but I can't intercept this error in order to do that. It seems from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/libavcodec_2h264dec_8c_source.html) (line 733) and [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/5.1/h264__slice_8c_source.html) (line 1888) that libav only logs the error and doesn't output this as a return value anywhere. I checked `AVFrame->decode_error_flags` (always zero) and return value from `avcodec_receive_frame`, which is always `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` with this type of error. Am I missing something?

Here's the related code:

```
    //codec initialization
    ctx->decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    ctx->av_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(ctx->decoder);

    if (ctx->decoder->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
        ctx->av_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

    ctx->av_ctx->flags2 |= AV_CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;

    avcodec_open2(ctx->av_ctx, ctx->decoder, NULL);
```

```
    //actual decoding
    ret = avcodec_send_packet(ctx->av_ctx, ctx->pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("err send pkt to decoding: %d\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(ctx->av_ctx, ctx->dec_frame);
        if (ctx->dec_frame->decode_error_flags) {
            //never executed
            printf("decode error flags %d\n", ctx->dec_frame->decode_error_flags);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            //need more pkts
            return ctx->scaled_frame;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            //never executed
            printf("err recv pkt from decoding: %d\n", ret);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may not be very effective, but what about checking `AVFrame::flags`? If you add lines like `if(ctx->dec_frame->flags & AV_FRAME_FLAG_CORRUPT){ /*error handling codes*/}` in the part after calling `avcodec_receive_frame()`, what will the results be like?

Comment: @MarkMiller unfortunately, this ctx->dec_frame->flags is also always zero

Comment: By the way, i managed to get rid of this error if I remove flags `AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED` and `AV_CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS` in initialization. Also, in certain error cases I get non zero `dec_frame->decode_error_flags`. But now I get `[h264 @ 0x7f070d6e3e80] no frame!` followed by `err send pkt to decoding: -1094995529` when sending SPS and PPS NALUs. Although, video don't freeze.